# How to add a 404 page to Single Page Scrolling App in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I'm new to React and trying to add a 404 page to my SPSA. This is how my `index.js` looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './dist/css/main.css';
import './../node_modules/react-fancybox/lib/fancybox.css';
import Nav from './js/Components/Nav';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import Landing from './js/Layout/Landing';
import Overview from './js/Layout/Overview';
import Solutions from './js/Layout/Solutions';
import Games from './js/Layout/Games';
import Platforms from './js/Layout/Platforms';
import Focus from './js/Layout/Focus';
import News from './js/Layout/News';
import Contact from './js/Layout/Contact';
import Catalogue from "./js/Layout/Catalogue";
import Game from "./js/Components/PlayGame";
import NotFound from "./js/Layout/NotFound";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const base_url = process.env.PUBLIC_URL;

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <div>
            <Route path={`${base_url}/`} component={withRouter(Nav)} />
            <Route exact path={`${base_url}/`} component={withRouter(Landing)} />
            <Route exact path={`${base_url}/`} component={withRouter(Overview)} />
            <Route exact path={`${base_url}/`} component={withRouter(Solutions)} />
            <Route exact path={`${base_url}/`} component={withRouter(Games)} />
            <Route exact path={`${base_url}/`} component={withRouter(Platforms)} />
            <Route exact path={`${base_url}/`} component={withRouter(Focus)} />
            <Route exact path={`${base_url}/`} component={withRouter(News)} />
            <Route exact path={`${base_url}/`} component={withRouter(Contact)} />
            <Route exact path={`${base_url}/catalogue`} component={withRouter(Catalogue)} />
            <Route exact path={`${base_url}/game/:gameid`} component={withRouter(Game)} />
            <Route component={withRouter(NotFound)} />
        </div>
    </Router>
    , document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

I searched around and found that I should be using `<Switch>` inside my Router but adding `<Switch>` makes my webpage blank and shows nothing. And currently the way I have it, the not found page shows at the bottom of my scroll while I only want it to appear when user enters the wrong URL. Where or how should my routes be implemented in order for me to render the 404 page only when user navigates to the wrong URL and not having it at all times in my scroll app home page? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**Update**

Tried doing the following:

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route path={`${base_url}/`} component={withRouter(Nav)} />
        <Route exact path={`${base_url}/`} component={withRouter(Landing)} />
        <Route exact path={`${base_url}/`} component={withRouter(Overview)} />
        <Route exact path={`${base_url}/`} component={withRouter(Solutions)} />
        <Route exact path={`${base_url}/`} component={withRouter(Games)} />
        <Route exact path={`${base_url}/`} component={withRouter(Platforms)} />
        <Route exact path={`${base_url}/`} component={withRouter(Focus)} />
        <Route exact path={`${base_url}/`} component={withRouter(News)} />
        <Route exact path={`${base_url}/`} component={withRouter(Contact)} />
        <Route exact path={`${base_url}/catalogue`} component={withRouter(Catalogue)} />
        <Route exact path={`${base_url}/game/:gameid`} component={withRouter(Game)} />
        <Route path="*" exact={true} component={withRouter(NotFound)} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

It shows me only the nav bar and nothing else, rest is all blank. And when I navigate to say `/catalogue` page, it shows that as blank as well. URL is changing but its not showing anything in the view.

**Solution**

Following did the trick for me as explained below by @Craig:

```
<Router>
    <div>
        <Route path={`${base_url}/`} component={withRouter(Nav)} />
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path={`${base_url}/`} render={() => (
                    <div>
                        <Landing/>
                        <Overview/>
                        <Solutions/>
                        <Games/>
                        <Platforms/>
                        <Focus/>
                        <News/>
                        <Contact/>
                    </div>
                )} />
            <Route exact path={`${base_url}/catalogue`} component={withRouter(Catalogue)} />
            <Route exact path={`${base_url}/game/:gameid`} component={withRouter(Game)} />
            <Route path="*" component={withRouter(NotFound)} />
        </Switch>
    </div>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `<div>` with a `<Switch>`. When you tried adding `<Switch>`, it sounds like you had the `<div>` as a child of the `<Switch>` and then all of your `<Route>` components under the div. You could move the div outside of the Router if you wanted to.

> All children of a `<Switch>` should be `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` elements.

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Switch/children-node

### Update

Change your new code to this:

```
<Router>
  <div>
    <Route path={`${base_url}/`} component={withRouter(Nav)} />
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path={`${base_url}/`} component={withRouter(Landing)} />
        <Route exact path={`${base_url}/`} component={withRouter(Overview)} />
        <Route exact path={`${base_url}/`} component={withRouter(Solutions)} />
        <Route exact path={`${base_url}/`} component={withRouter(Games)} />
        <Route exact path={`${base_url}/`} component={withRouter(Platforms)} />
        <Route exact path={`${base_url}/`} component={withRouter(Focus)} />
        <Route exact path={`${base_url}/`} component={withRouter(News)} />
        <Route exact path={`${base_url}/`} component={withRouter(Contact)} />
        <Route exact path={`${base_url}/catalogue`} component={withRouter(Catalogue)} />
        <Route exact path={`${base_url}/game/:gameid`} component={withRouter(Game)} />
        <Route path={"*"} exact={true} component={withRouter(NotFound)} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
</Router>
```

The switch will only render the first match.

Comment: Please see my question, I updated it to show my findings after implementing what you suggested.

Comment: Take the route for the nav bar out of the switch. Put it above the switch but still inside the router. The switch is only going to render the first thing that matches.

Comment: Doing that throws me an error `A <Router> may have only one child element`. Also, if I do the above, I'm unable to navigate to other pages too.

Comment: Sorry, try this. Div inside the router, then the route and the switch. Updated code in answer.

Comment: This did the trick. Though I render the landing and the other pages in one route now since its a SPSA but wrapping the div and moving the nav out did the trick. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

add the below code inside your switch as follows:

```
 <Switch>
    /* All your routes here */
    <Route path='*' component={AppFallbackComponent} />
  </Switch>
```

What it does is, it renders the component `AppFallbackComponent` for all scenarios when the path in URL does not match any of the above configured routes. This can be used for all such scenarios and for 404 etc.

Remember, the route I mentioned should be added as the last route inside switch, this would mean the fallback would get executed after react router has matched all routes defined above.

Comment: Please see my question, I updated it to show my findings after implementing what you suggested.

Comment: <Route path="*" component={withRouter(NotFound)} /> Use this, never use {} and "" together.

Comment: Changing that did not do much. Still seeing the same issue, my entire view is blank with just the navbar.

Comment: @MuradAli Remove exact={true} from last route, plus you don't need withRouter for components directly attached with routing. Use this: <Route path="*" component={NotFound) />. In case this does not work, share the errors you see in console.